# Calling a C# web service's method using volley in android

Tags: c#, android, web-services, kotlin, android-volley

I have read almost all the related questions, but unfortunately no one solved my problem.
My problem is that I have created a C# web service and created four methods into it for different purposes and one of them called getSections here it is:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string getSections()
    {
        connectToDB();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Sections", link);

        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    }
```

when I test the web service from the visual studio it shows links to the four methods to invoke them one by one, all of them work fine, so I uploaded them to my server. After that I tried to access to getSections method from my app using volley and here how I have done:

```
private fun getAllSections() {
    /**
     * Start Downloading all the sections
     */


    var uri="http://......../myProject/WebService1.asmx?op=getSections";

    val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uri, Listener<String> { response ->

        Log.i("SectionsResponse", response)
        Toast.makeText(this,"SectionsResponse: "+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }, object : Response.ErrorListener {
        override fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError?) {
            if (error != null) {
                Log.i("SectionsError:", error.message.toString())
                Toast.makeText(baseContext,"error"+error.message.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
          }
        }
    }) {
        override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            val params=HashMap<String,String>()
            //params.put("a","aa")
            return params
        }
    }

    if (Funs().isOnline(this)) {

        val requesQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        requesQueue.add<String>(stringRequest)

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, resources.getString(R.string.connectionFailed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    /**
     * End Downloading all the sections
     */
}
```

After all above I am getting a null result from the error listener which means that the url is not valid or not found.
so

> what is the valid way to access to the method into c# web service using volley library.

appreciate any help.

Comment: If it is `GET` request, use `Request.Method.GET` in `StringRequest` not `Request.Method.POST`. If that doesn't work, try the same URL with Postman client and confirm that it works fine. If you get any error with Volley, please [edit] the question and post error logs here.

Comment: We use ksoap2 for this purpose. It works quite good for us.

Comment: @Shashanth I tried to use Get method, but the result I got is all the content of the web page not the result of getSections method

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# stuff. Are you sure it returns 'JSON` or `XML` data as response? I'd suggest you to use C# Web API for this as it returns JSON response and it's more convenient to.parse data in client side than XML data.

Comment: @Shashanth would you mind providing me with a lint to an example.

and speaking of the JSON yes, you are right the web service returns XML, but I have used an external library to change the dataTable to json

Comment: Most of the modern applications use JSON data now. It's hard to parse XML data and consumes more bandwidth as it's heavy. Where JSON is light weight and easy to parse. You can refer Microsoft's [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) for Web API 2. Good luck